# Are there any COMMON light stand and softbox - which would work both with strobe lights AND continuous LED light

Tags: strobes, softbox, led-lighting

In near future, I would require continuous LED light for videography (on-stage, like he platform of bride and groom in Indian wedding).
Also, I would require studio strobes when I plan to shoot Models inside studio.
So, I plan to buy both studio strobes (like  Godox SK 400 II) and also continuous LED light (like Simpex Pro HD LED).

Now, my question is : **are there any common Light stand and common light modifiers (like soft box - rectangular or octagonal etc) which can be used for setting up both strobe & continuous light ??**
Probably, the light holders in the stand would differ and can be set as case to case basis (strobe or continuous)??

Comment: I think this is too broad as currently stated. Figure out what models of lights you actually want, and what kinds of mounts and/or adaptors are supported for those lights, and from there you can determine what stands are compatible. There are some common standards, but they're not necessarily universal.

Comment: A light stand is a fairly universal piece of equipment. More unique attachments are used between the stand and the light. The soft box will generally use a manufacturer specific speedring style attachment to get directly to the strobe. Mixing and matching doesn't always work without custom making an attachment, usually involving judicious use of alligator clips.

Answer (score 3):

Lighting stands are pretty much standard; almost everything that you would be using outside of industrial applications (like "real" cinema, television and theatre llighting) will use "baby" spigot connections (5/8" or 16mm). "Junior" is ultra-heavy-duty for lights weighing in the tens of kilos, and "senior" would be handy for supporting small armoured vehicles in the air - both are well outside of the normal fare for wedding and location work.

As for modifiers, the closest thing there is to a handy universal standard is what's being used on the Godox SK400 flashes you're looking at: the Bowens S-mount for reflectors and modifiers. There are continuous lights available with S-mount built in, including those from Godox, and adapters to S-mount for other LED and hot-light systems. Using a Bowens mount means that you have only one set of speed rings to worry about, and can even use folding parabolic softlights, rather than having to keep a whole collection of rings and rods of different lengths. But that means you won't be able to use a light head that's just a bunch of Edison-base sockets; it'll need to be a proper light head.

Comment: Additionally, there's probably zero benefit in trying to modify the LED's (softbox) in that situation... it's extremely unlikely that you will have lights or modifiers large enough for there to be any benefit at the distances required.

Answer (score 0):

LED panels & strobes both can be made to fit on common lighting 'hats'. Mine all use the same base fitting so the stands are interchangeable - but getting an umbrella to fit round a panel would be a much harder task, & the amount of light you'd lose would likely be prohibitive - the panel would be in its own way reverse-mounted, facing into the umbrella.

Why not just invest in some diffuser gels for the panels, clipped to the barn doors, or some [flags](https://www.essentialphoto.co.uk/product/60x90cm-24-x-36-professional-foldable-flag-panel-kit/#image-3)* you can mount in front?

ahh, I just looked up those Simex lights - they're not panels, they're a bunch of light bulbs… & in fact seem to have the exact same mounts as all my lighting, so you could probably just about squeeze them in a softbox, forward facing.

Anyway, this is a standard budget stand/strobe adaptor, $£€ 5 - 10 or so, which will fit on any stand the Simexes do..

[image]

<sup>*Random Google result.</sup>